# Unit testing in plain PHP

Tags: php, unit-testing

I am curious to know how we can test our code using unit test in plain PHP.

Is their any guideline for this.

And how we can do unit testing when we use MVC architecture to create website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's basically only one answer to this question: [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit).

It's the biggest testing framework in PHP. Best documented, most users, most capabilities, industry-standard. All you're looking for. The [manual is here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html).

As for MVC: writing testable code doesn't have anything to do with the design pattern you're programming by.

Comment: By installing, configuring, writing tests, running?

Comment: @YogiYogesh Start with the [manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) and go from there?

Answer (score 3):

You can write unit tests without any framework at all, but you'll find that you are writing a lot of the concepts yourself that you could get for free from [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) or [EnhancePHP](http://www.enhance-php.com/).

In particular, the framework will have helpers that allow you to assert the test, helpers to give you fakes to use in your tests (especially useful in your case if you are using an MVC pattern) and a method of running and displaying the results.

If you look at the source code of a unit testing framework, you can see how all of these helpers work and it will ultimately be quicker to learn a framework than to write one.

Here is an example of a manual test - we fail the test if the result isn't right, or if there is an exception:

```
$passed = true;
try {
    $result = $target->addTwoNumbers(5, 2);
    $passed = 7 === $result;
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    $passed = false;
}

return $passed;
```

When you use a framework, this becomes much more readable:

```
$result = $target->addTwoNumbers(5, 2);
Assert::areIdentical(7, $result);
```

In both examples, I have omitted the code to set up the test, i.e. create `$target` as it doesn't add any meaning to the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

There is also SimpleTest ( http://www.simpletest.org/ ) - which is a very light. without the baggage of a lot of the other test-suites.

You can also use automation tools such as Selenium which essentially mimics a user sitting browsing with a mouse too - obviously you have to train it and assign tests etc.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use PHPUnit or other unit testing frameworks. I did not like the idea of adding a lot of extra code to my projects, so I wrote a unit tester myself.

For basic unit testing you only need 2 PHP files/classes. One that performs the actual tests, and one that is the base class for a unittest.

I wrote a [blog](http://www.ganymedes.be/index/blog/3) with code to demonstrate how this can be done. The unit tester can be seen in action [here](http://unittester-online.example.ganymedes.be/).

I my perception, when a question at SO pops up like this, most answers are : do not do it yourself use xxx. However this comes with a penalty: it will bloat your code, and make the completed project bigger, more difficult to maintain and dependent on third party code.

Comment: Links are dead and the ideas are not written here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.phpunit.intro.php

And the best is to use PHPUnit for unit testing.